# Can't resolve getSystemService(FINGERPRINT_SERVICE)

Tags: android, android-studio, fingerprint

Very strange issue faced. The following code

```
fingerprintManager = (FingerprintManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.FINGERPRINT_SERVICE);
```

underlines in red color the Context.FINGERPRINT_SERVICE and says: "must be one of following... " and prints me all the possible system services, where FINGERPRINT is absent. But if i go into sources of Context class I can see the FINGERPRINT_SERVICE constant present. 
Permission included in manifest.
Build tools is 23.0.1.
Worked in another project with the same studio and api level. What is wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `compileSdkVersion` is lower than 23, presumably.

Comment: compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23'

Comment: @EvgeniyMishustin: Unless you are somehow still using Maps V1, replace that with `compileSdkVersion 23` and see if you have better luck. Also, make sure that you are on a fairly current version of Android Studio (e.g., 2.1.2).

Comment: it worked when I did as suggested and validated caches.

Answer (score 1):

Following worked for me:

```
FingerprintManagerCompat fingerprintManagerCompat = FingerprintManagerCompat.from(getActivity());
```

Comment: How is this supposed to answer the question? The OP has already stated that the error he was getting was from `FINGERPRINT_SERVICE` not being recognized as a member of `Context`.

Comment: Edited. My compileSdkVersion 23 minSdkVersion 18 and targetSdkVersion 23